# How to update or extend dictionary keys without overwriting or duplicating existing values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists in which the keys are keywords and the values are lists of page numbers in a book ("page number dictionary"):

e.g. `{'Person A': [125], 'Person B': [95, 97], 'Event A': [11], 'Event B': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Place A': [116], 'Place B': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285]}`

In a second step, I would like to replace keys that are synonyms for new keywords while merging their lists of page numbers:

e.g. `{'Person AB': [ 95, 97, 125], 'Event AB': [11, 115, 118, 132, 134], 'Place AB': [116, 181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285]}`

Old keywords and new keywords are mapped in a CSV file.

My **workflow** is:

1. finding the page numbers for old keywords in the PDF file and writing them to a list
2. mapping the old keywords to new keywords according to my CSV file
3. writing new keywords and their lists of page numbers to a dictionary
4. updating existing key:value pairs without over-writing or duplicating existing values
5. writing the final dictionary to CSV and TXT

**EDIT:**

Here is a [link to the complete script](https://github.com/MonikaBarget/DigitalHistory/blob/master/BookINDEX_find&replaceKEYWORDS.py).

**My problem** is that "merging" key:value pairs when new page numbers for the some new keywords are written to the dictionary does not work.

a) The `extend` function results in many duplicates being written to my lists of values.

SCRIPT:

```
# check if nw as key already exists in dict and add OR update values
                if nw in page_dict.keys():
                    page_dict[nw].extend(page_list)
                    print(page_dict)
                else:
                    page_dict[nw]=page_list
                    print(page_dict)
```

OUTPUT:

```
'Bavaria': [117, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 124, 125, 131, 133, 134, 135, 139, 144, 147, 148, 151, 152, 234, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 124, 125, 131, 133, 134, 135, 139, 144, 147, 148, 151, 152, 117, 144, 190, 161], 
'Beijing': [23, 34, 35], 
'Bohemia': [117, 135, 139, 117, 117], 
'Boston': [17, 113, 114, 188, 237, 269, 310], 
'Brabant': [82], 
'Brandenburg': [174, 175, 183, 187]
```

b) the `update` function results in the `'dict' object is not callable` error:

SCRIPT:

```
                if nw in page_dict():
                   page_dict.update({nw: page_list}) 
                else:
                    page_dict[nw]=page_list
                print(page_dict)
```

OUTPUT: script breaks.

Which function do I need to combine existing values without overwriting or duplicating them?

Comment: You might consider using a JSON file rather than TXT so you can more easily serialize and deserialize the relationships.

Comment: JSON is a great idea, but I actually need to submit some plain text list of final keywords and page numbers to the publisher for a printed book. I will work on a script this evening and edit my post later.

Comment: You don't need to "flatten" if something is already flat - use list.extend instead of list.append to keep it flat. Use sets to get rid of duplicates instantly. So basically after you merged everything already, do `sorted(set(list_with_values))` to convert it to set (get rid of duplicates) and then instantly into a sorted list.

Comment: What does your input look like (a small sample with faked data will do), what should your output look like (for that faked data)?

Answer (score 1):

An attempt :

```py
from itertools import chain


page_numbers_by_keyword = {
    "potato": [4, 7, 26, 80],
    "potatoes": [11, 26],
    "spud": [59],  # an informal UK synonym for "potato"
    "apple": [6, 23],
    "apples": [23, 26],
    "strawberry": [44],
}
synonyms_by_keyword = {
    "potato": {"potatoes", "spud"},
    "apple": {"apples"},
    "strawberry": {},
}

synonyms = set(chain(*synonyms_by_keyword.values()))


page_numbers_by_synonymic_keyword = {}
for keyword, pages in page_numbers_by_keyword.items():
    is_synonym = keyword in synonyms
    if is_synonym:
        continue
    page_numbers_by_synonymic_keyword[keyword] = set(pages)
    keyword_synonyms = synonyms_by_keyword.get(keyword, ())
    for keyword_synonym in keyword_synonyms:
        page_numbers_by_synonymic_keyword[keyword] |= set(page_numbers_by_keyword.get(keyword_synonym))  # add to the set

print("\n".join(f"{keyword}: {sorted(pages)}" for keyword, pages in sorted(page_numbers_by_synonymic_keyword.items())))
```

gives

```
apple: [6, 23, 26]
potato: [4, 7, 11, 26, 59, 80]
strawberry: [44]
```

which is the combination of what I defined initially in `page_numbers_by_keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to de-duplicate and sort each list in the dictionary of lists when writing the `key:value` pairs to CSV:

```
# write each dictionary to one row in new .CSV file

            with open('C:\\#####\\BRILL_book.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as x:
                writer = csv.writer(x)
                for key, value in page_dict.items():
                    writer.writerow([key, sorted(set(value))]) # sort and de-deduplicate list
                    f.close()
```

More elegant solutions are welcome.